# Can the web version of iCloud be configured to become the default mailto link handler?

Tags: icloud, email, unix

How can I set up iCloud as the default email provider in my browser? I am using Linux and if I click on a mailto link in a web page it goes to my Gmail account. Can this be changed to make it go to my iCloud account?

Comment: This isn't a question about Apple or iCloud but depends on your Linux distribution and/or your browser. See if this page helps if you're using Firefox---https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/925377

Comment: This is welcome here simply by virtue of it being about using the iCloud service Apple provides, but @CraftyThumber might be correct that if it's not answered here we might want to look at migrating it to one of the linux partner sites in a week or two.